# Adding per-object permissions to django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

**Background**

I'm developing a django app for a vacation rental site. It will have two types of users, renters and property managers.

I'd like the property managers to be able to manage their rental properties in the django admin. However, they should only be able to manage their own properties.

I realize the default django admin doesn't support this. I'm wondering how much trouble it would be to add this functionality, and, if it's feasible, what the best way to handle it is.

---

**Goal**

Ideally, I picture it working something like this:

`auth` already allows permissions like this:

```
vacation | rental | Can add rental
vacation | rental | Can change rental
vacation | rental | Can delete rental
```

I'd like to change this to something like:

```
vacation | rental | Can add any rental
vacation | rental | Can change any rental
vacation | rental | Can delete any rental
vacation | rental | Can add own rental
vacation | rental | Can change own rental
vacation | rental | Can delete own rental
```

---

**Possible solution**

How would the framework decide if the rental (or whatever) belongs to the user? I'm thinking it checks the `vacation.Rental` class to see if it has a `ForeignKey` to `auth.User` (possibly having some particular name, like 'owner').

- On creating a new `vacation.Rental`, the value of the `ForeignKey` field would be forced to the current user's id. The `ForeignKey` field would not be displayed on the form.
- On listing rentals, only rentals with the `ForeignKey` matching the current user would be displayed.
- On changing rentals, only rentals with the `ForeignKey` matching the current user would be displayed. The `ForeignKey` field would not be displayed on the form.

Of course, this should be able to work for any model having an appropriate `ForeignKey` field, not just our `vacation.Rental` model.

Does this sound feasible so far, or should I be going in a different direction?

---

**Complications**

Now, here's the tricky part; I'm not sure how to handle this. Let's say a `Rental` can have many "RentalPhotos." `RentalPhoto` has a `ForeignKey` to `Rental`. Users should be able to add photos to their own rentals. However, the photos don't have a user `ForeignKey`, so there's no way to directly find out who owns the photo.

Can this be solved by some trickery in the framework, following `ForeignKey`s until an object is found with a `ForeignKey` to user? Or should I take the easy way out and give `RentalPhoto` (and everything else 'belonging' to `Rental`) its own `ForeignKey` to the appropriate`auth.User`? The second approach would invite unneeded redundancy, the first would probably require unnecessary processing overhead...

If I'm going entirely astray please don't hesitate to point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I would simply add a method to each model `is_owned_by(user)`, and it is upto the model to decide if it is owned by that user or not. In most case `is_owned_by` can be a generic function in a base model class and you can tweak it in special cases. e.g.

```
class RentalPhoto(BaseModel):
    def is_owned_by(self, user):
        return self.rental.is_owned_by(user)
```

This is generic enough and being explicit you will have full control how things behave.

To add new permission you can add that to your models e.g.

```
class Rental(models.Model):
    # ...
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("can_edit_any", "Can edit any rentals"),
        )
```

I think instead of adding two permission for `any` and `own`, you should add only `own` permission , so each object already has `can_edit` which you can treat as user can edit only his object, and if user has permission can_edit_any than only he is allowed to edit all

Using this we can extend auth by adding a custom backend e.g.

```
class PerObjectBackend(ModelBackend):

    def has_perm(self, user_obj, perm, obj=None):
        allowed = ModelBackend.has_perm(self, user_obj, perm)
        if perm.find('any') >=0 :
            return allowed

        if perm.find('edit') >=0 or perm.find('delete') >=0:
            if obj is None:
                raise Exception("Perm '%s' needs an object"%perm)
            if not obj.is_owned_by(user_obj):
                return False

        return allowed
```

This is a very quick implemenation, in reality you can extend permission objects to check if it needs and object or not e.g. `permission.is_per_object` instead of doing crude string search but that should also work if you have standard names

Comment: Thanks, Anurag; it's not as generic as I'd like but I'll consider it. How can I tie this into `auth` so my new permissions show up in the list?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to implement your own Permission Backend, I recommend you to use https://github.com/chrisglass/django-rulez You will do what you want in a much easier way.

Answer (score 1):

It's in [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset).

Basically you create custom admin class for your model, and define the method `get_queryset`. In your case it could be something like below. Super user would see all rentals, while owner only his.

```
class RentalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super(RentalAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return qs
        return qs.filter(owner=request.user)
```

Here's another possible lead: https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/RowLevelPermissions

Answer (score 0):

> Can this be solved by some trickery in
>   the framework, following ForeignKeys
>   until an object is found with a
>   ForeignKey to user?

I don't see where there is trickery necessairy:
RentalPhoto -> Rental -> User
So to get the User for a particular RentalPhoto you would call something like this in the instance:

```
photo.rental.user
```

Following multiple relations in one step can be considered as non-trickery.

Comment: That would work for this particular case, but I want to do it in a generic way -- "Of course, this should be able to work for any model having an appropriate `ForeignKey` field, not just our `vacation.Rental` [and related] model[s]."

Comment: There are like dozends of possible ways to be more generic. E.g. having a model.Ownable which defines the field owner and extend it in the ownable Models.

Comment: This answer isn't very helpful. It leaves most of the question unanswered. Maybe I did a bad job of explaining the question?

Comment: If you can tell me why using model inheritance doesn't help your case, I better understand what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Rental(models.Model):
    owner: User = models.ForeignKey(
        User, verbose_name='owner', related_name='rentals',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=False
    )
    # owner_id automatically gets created by Django. Optionally annotate to help your IDE
    owner_id: int

    def is_owned_by(self, user: User):
        # You can use self.owner == user, or self.owner.id == user.id. 
        # But this way owner data won't be fetched from the database
        if self.owner_id == user.id:
            return True
        return False


class RentalPhoto(models.Model):

    rental: Rental = models.ForeignKey(
        Rental, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='rental_photos',
        blank=False, null=False,
    )

    def is_owned_by(self, user: User):
        return self.rental.is_owned_by(user)


class RentalPhotoAdminInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = RentalPhoto
    extra = 1


@admin.register(Rental)
class RentalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    inlines = (RentalPhotoAdminInline,)

    # staff members can only view/operate their rentals
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request)
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            queryset = queryset.filter(owner_id=request.user.id)

        return queryset

    def save_model(self, request, obj: Rental, form, change):
        # set rental owner on admin save
        if obj.owner_id is None:
            obj.owner = request.user
        obj.save()

    def has_view_or_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        allowed = super().has_view_or_change_permission(request, obj)
        if obj is None:
            return allowed
        return request.user.is_superuser or obj.is_owned_by(request.user)

    def has_view_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        allowed = super().has_view_permission(request, obj)
        if obj is None:
            return allowed
        return request.user.is_superuser or obj.is_owned_by(request.user)

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        allowed = super().has_change_permission(request, obj)
        if obj is None:
            return allowed
        return request.user.is_superuser or obj.is_owned_by(request.user)

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        allowed = super().has_delete_permission(request, obj)
        if obj is None:
            return allowed
        return request.user.is_superuser or obj.is_owned_by(request.user)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.